# RPi Zero vga display problem

Tags: hdmi, pi-zero

RPi not showing up display when connected to mini hdmi to hdmi converted and then to hdmi to vga converter.

both the converters are tested, working... if its not possible then how to access rpi zero using a vga display?

Comment: Hang on, your going from mini HDMI to HDMI then to VGA? Just because the 2 converters work independently does not mean they are going to work together. I suggest using a mini HDMI to VGA adapter. Alternatively you could give VNC Viewer a look. That would require VNC Viewer to be installed on a computer connected to the monitor, and VNC server to be installed on the Pi.

Comment: @DarthVader mini HDMI is exactly the same as full-size HDMI from electrical point of view.

Comment: Have you tried setting `hdmi_safe=1` in `config.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

I use this HDMI to VGA converter
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01I3K67FK

without problems together with Mini HDMI to HDMI cable from Pihut Essentials to connect Pi Zero to VGA monitor.

I received this Pi VGA adapter, but have not tested it sofar:
www.aliexpress.com/item/VGA-adapter-666-for-Raspberry-Pi-A-B-Raspberry-Pi-2-Model-B-RPI-3-Model/32706415666.html
[image]

Hermann.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my rpi zero w, the lights would light up and the monitor would not display a "no signal warning" it turns out the image on my sd card was for a rpi 2 b+ make sure your image is the right one.

Comment: If you are talking about Raspbian then there is no specific version for any Raspberry Pi model. Raspbian runs on all RasPis.

Answer (score -1):

Too many connections can affect the signals.
Use a few conversions for this is not true and it is better to use a converter

use this :
[mini HTMI to VGA](https://www.amazon.de/Cable-Matters-Mini-HDMI-Adapter-Stromkabel-Schwarz/dp/B007TWXAVI)

Comment: A mini HDMI to HDMI adapter is a very simple passive item.  Why would it make a difference in this case?

Comment: Too much connections can affect the signals

Comment: True enough!  I think this should be qualified by saying it's a *possibility* and not something that is definitely a significant factor though.  Really it would mean the mini adapter is substandard in the same sense a low quality HDMI cable could be a cause of signal loss.

Comment: i tried on my hdmi tv, and its working perfectly with mini hdmi to hdmi convertor... i think you are right @ha

Comment: i think you are right @hamedtorky